# Can I use "going at" in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

> A man shouts at Ben from across the bar.
>
> Man: *Why don't you just fuck off!*
>
> Ben is held back from going at the man.

Is the last sentence correct and clear to mean that Ben is prevented from running over to the man to attack him physically?

Could it be written in another and better way?

Comment: What do you mean "better"?  Did you consider "from attacking the man"  if so, why did you reject it?

Answer (score 1):

That is proper grammar.

But you could maybe say "attacking", but then you have to remove the "at":

> Ben is held back from attacking the man.

As mentioned in the dictionary, the meaning of "attacking" is:

> launching or engaging in a military or violent physical attack.

And for "going at someone" it is:

> to attack someone or something violently, using either force or very strong language: The candidates went at each other during the debate.

Comment: Would "running at" be more clear than "going at" then? Would it be natural?

Comment: @student123 running at could be an option as well